# How to remove trailing characters in filenames in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have a bunch of media files like those below:

```
tvshow.s01e11]Bloodlines.avi
tvshow.s01e12]suffer.avi
tvshow.s01e13]NotMe.avi
```

I would like to rename them to

```
tvshow.s01e11.avi
tvshow.s01e12.avi
tvshow.s01e13.avi
```

I’ve tried using rename but evidently I’m not getting the syntax right because it fails.

Comment: If you ever want to do this in a gui, `krename` is lovely. It has all sorts of powerful options and shows you what it's going to do before it actually does it. You could even use it to test out patterns that you could use in bash later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will rename the files. You need the \w* to signify any number of alphanumeric characters.

```
rename 's/\]\w*//' *
```

Reference:
http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#UsingSimpleWildcards

Comment: Note that this requires the Perl `rename` utility, not the [one with same name from util-linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html). See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148380/170373) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22577767/6372809)

Answer (score 14):

In shell, one could do simply:

```
for x in *]*.avi ; do 
    mv -i "$x" "${x%]*.avi}.avi"
done
```

The shell can produce a list of the filenames with just a regular glob, and
`${var%pattern}` removes the (shortest) matching pattern from the end of the string in variable `var`. Since the final extension is always `.avi`, I just removed it with the pattern and added it back. With the quotes, this should work with file names containing spaces too, like `Fancy Name for a Show.s01e01]Asdf.avi`

Comment: @NoviceC the extglob pattern wasn't a bad idea. Actually, something like `${x/]*([^.])}` should do, it removes a bracket and any number of non-dots. (though fails if there are other brackets or dots, since it's not locked to the end of the string)

Comment: That's a good point. But I really just overcomplicated the issue when I should have went with `${x/]*.avi}` and just added a `.avi` like you. But I was also unsatisfied with how spaces in the name would break `(\`find . -name '*]*.avi'\`)`. I was happy to provide a limited standard unix command method, since rename isn't, but this blows mine out of the water.

Answer (score 2):

This is all kinds of impractical - the other answers are much faster and shorter - but...

You can use PowerShell! Microsoft [open-sourced it](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) recently and made it cross-platform. For downloads and installation instructions for your OS, see [the "Get PowerShell" section](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell).

Once you get it installed, you can use this brief script:

```
Get-ChildItem -File '*]*.avi' | ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName (($_.Name -Split ']')[0] + '.avi')
}
```

Basically, it goes through each object in the current directory that is a file matching `*]*.avi`, gets the part before the bracket, tacks `.avi` back onto it, and assigns that as the new name.

To run it directly from Bash, use this semi-golfed one-liner:

```
powershell -command $'gci -File \'*]*.avi\'|%{rename-item $_ -NewName (($_.Name -Split \']\')[0]+\'.avi\')}'
```

Quote escaping courtesy of [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16605140/2825369).

(Tested in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. There's probably a much shorter way of doing it with PowerShell, but I wanted to show something that's comprehensible to people who don't know regular expressions.)

Comment: Rube Goldberg would be proud! Regexes are a real PITA to learn, but they're worth it many times over - even at the rudimentary level I'm able to use them at.

Answer (score 1):

Debian has a package called [mmv](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/mmv) which might also be available in other distros, and should be easy enough to compile from source if not. It allows you to write this:

```
mmv '*]*.avi' '#1.avi'
```

You can read the [Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mln.1.html) for this command for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This will search for the pattern and replace the text using sed.

```
 $sed 's/\(.*]\)[a-zA-z0-9].*\(.avi\)/\1\2/' filename
```